# Alternative to NSStatusItem.button (NSStatusBarButton) OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I'm building an app with a status bar button, I'm using a NSPopover to display a view on top of it. The code to do that looks like this:

`popover.showRelativeToRect(button.bounds, ofView: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinY)`

I want to do this same functionality in OSX 10.9. The button is not available < 10.10. I've looked at the source, and I see that most of the attributes I need are  there, I simply need a way to emulate the buttons bounds, and view - at this point. How could one go about that?

Suggestions for completely replacing a NSStatusItem.button are very useful as well.

Comment: Could I ask why I'm getting down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mavericks use the deprecated implementation of `NSStatusItem`.

This is the interface:

```
@interface NSStatusItem (NSStatusItemDeprecated)

/* 
 These are softly deprecated methods of NSStatusItem.
 Their past and current behavior is to forward their calls onto the button property.
 They will be formally deprecated in a later release. 
 */
@property (nullable) SEL action;
@property (nullable) SEL doubleAction;
@property (nullable, weak) id target;
@property (nullable, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nullable, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedTitle;
@property (nullable, strong) NSImage *image;
@property (nullable, strong) NSImage *alternateImage;
@property (getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
@property BOOL highlightMode;
@property (nullable, copy) NSString *toolTip;
- (NSInteger)sendActionOn:(NSInteger)mask;

/*
 Custom views should not be set on a status item.
 The button property with a template image will allow proper styling of the status item in various states and contexts and should be used instead.
 */
@property (nullable, strong) NSView *view;
- (void)drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:(NSRect)rect withHighlight:(BOOL)highlight;
- (void)popUpStatusItemMenu:(NSMenu*)menu;

@end
```